# Can bitconverter convert bytes into template type "T"?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a template method that reads float or double values from the file through binary reader.

I can't use Binaryreader.readSingle or Binaryreader.readDouble methods as they are too specific... May be read bytes and use bitConverter to convert into either float or double. But can the bitConverter can convert bytes into template type "T" ?

```
// Note: T type will be either float or double 
static void readValues<T>(string fileName, T[] arr, int arrLen)
{
   BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open));

   for(int i = 0; i < arrLen; i++)
   {
      // Have to use one of the methods to read the values
      // which one to use

      // 1. To read float
      //arr[i] = reader.readSingle();

      // 2. To read Double
      //arr[i] = reader.readDouble();


   }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you should explain what the format of the data in the file is (e.g. how are the values written to the file, and in what format)

Answer (score 2):

As always some persons (me) remain fixated on certain instruments... If all you have is a hammer, all your problems will seem like nails... Without using Expression trees (if anyone is interested, the other version with Expression trees is in the history of the post). One class to cache a delegate to the "right" method based on the generic type T. Another class to make everything work as an extension method.

```
public static class BinaryReaderEx
{
    public static T Read<T>(this BinaryReader br)
    {
        return BinaryReader<T>.Read(br);
    }
}

public static class BinaryReader<T>
{
    public static readonly Func<BinaryReader, T> Read;

    static BinaryReader()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        if (type == typeof(bool))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, bool>)(p => p.ReadBoolean()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(char))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, char>)(p => p.ReadChar()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(string))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, string>)(p => p.ReadString()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(sbyte))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, sbyte>)(p => p.ReadSByte()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(short))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, short>)(p => p.ReadInt16()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, int>)(p => p.ReadInt32()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(long))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, long>)(p => p.ReadInt64()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(byte))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, byte>)(p => p.ReadByte()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(ushort))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, ushort>)(p => p.ReadUInt16()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(uint))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, uint>)(p => p.ReadUInt32()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(ulong))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, ulong>)(p => p.ReadUInt64()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(float))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, float>)(p => p.ReadSingle()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(double))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, double>)(p => p.ReadDouble()));
        }
        else if (type == typeof(decimal))
        {
            Read = (Func<BinaryReader, T>)(Delegate)((Func<BinaryReader, decimal>)(p => p.ReadDecimal()));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
using (var br = new BinaryReader(ms))
{
    //byte b = BinaryReader<bool>.Read(br);
    //double d = BinaryReader<double>.Read(br);
    //string s = BinaryReader<string>.Read(br);

    // Or

    byte b = br.Read<bool>();
    double d = br.Read<double>();
    string s = br.Read<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good situation where generics would be a good design choice.

You would be much better off writing two functions, one that takes in an array of doubles and one that takes in an array of floats. The compiler will choose the correct overload depending on which array you pass in and it may even end up being less code after you throw in all the error handling (What if I pass in an array of ints?) and casting than the generics version.